# Remember pageNumber with ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, page-refresh

I want to a ask a question about ajax. I am using  asp.net mvc 3 and i have a gridview which is refresh with ajax requests. when i click pager's numbers it can refresh with ajax request but when i refresh the page It doesn't remember current page. ı don't want to use session to remember page number. Can anybody give me any other solution?

My get Method

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult VeriAktarimYontemi()
        {
            EDocSis.DTO.SearchDTO<EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO, EDocSis.DAL.EFatura.KurumVeriAktarim> kurumVeriAktarim = new EDocSis.DTO.SearchDTO<EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO, EDocSis.DAL.EFatura.KurumVeriAktarim>();
            EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO searchDTO = new EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO();
            int pageNumber= (ViewBag.PageNumber==null)?0:Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.PageNumber);
            return View(kurumVeriAktarim);
```

and my ajax method which is request from partial view,

```
 public ActionResult _VeriAktarim(EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO searchObject, int id, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.PageNumber = page;
            int sayfaNumarasi = page.HasValue ? page.Value : 1;
            EDocSis.DTO.SearchDTO<EDocSis.DTO.KurumVeriAktarimDTO, EDocSis.DAL.EFatura.KurumVeriAktarim> liste = searchObject.KurumVeriAktarimlariSayfali(sayfaNumarasi);
            return PartialView("_VeriAktarim", liste);
        }
```